# Using Segment to send Mixpanel revenue server-side

Tags: node.js, analytics, server-side, mixpanel, segment

I'm trying to send a server-side revenue call to Segment for Mixpanel so that it will show up as revenue. I know that with Mixpanel has a `track_charge` call, and Segment suggests using a `revenue` event. Has anyone does this on the server-side (specifically with Node.js)? Here's my current call

```
analytics.track({
    userId: transaction.user.username,
    event: 'revenue',
    properties: {
        price: 1.00
    }
});
```